# What's the difference between these two java arrayList.add()

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public void findCombination(List<List<Integer>> ans, ArrayList<Integer> tmp, int [] candidates, int remain, int start){
    if(remain < 0){
        return ;
    }
    else if(remain == 0){
        ans.add(new ArrayList<>(tmp));
    }
    else{
        for(int i = start; i < candidates.length; i++){
            tmp.add(candidates[i]);
            findCombination(ans, tmp, candidates, remain-candidates[i], i);
            tmp.remove(tmp.size()-1);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, I find that when I change `ans.add(new ArrayList<>(tmp))` to `ans.add(tmp)`. It will not work... So I want to ask, why? And what's the difference between `ans.add(new ArrayList<>(tmp))` and `ans.add(tmp)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that when you use `ans.add(new ArrayList<>(tmp))` you are creating a copy of the list `tmp` instead of addind it to the list.

If you add it using `ans.add(tmp)` any change you make to the list `tmp` will be reflected in the list that you did put there.